# My iPad application is not displaying properly while it is running on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9

I have developed an iPad application which is working fine on iPad mini and iPad 2. The issue is while I try to run it in iPad Pro, it displays like in the size of iPad Air 2. Please refer the screenshot. It is working fine in iPad Pro simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding default image

2048 x 2732 (for portrait)

2732 x 2048 (for landscape)

and if you are using storyboard you can also do this

open storyboard select screen change wAny hAny to wRegular hRegular and see if its reflect in preview? as per you requirement.

Comment: I have used 2732 x 2048 (for landscape) image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply constraints so that the view resize according to the screen size. What is the resolution of the image? In [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/) are you using [scaleToFit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733113/scaling-uiimageview-to-fit-width-with-autolayout)?

Share more code. 
 [See AppleDoc on Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)
OR
[See a tutorial on autolayout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Also see:

[How to resize a fixed width and height UIImageView with auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036333/how-to-resize-a-fixed-width-and-height-uiimageview-with-auto-layout)

[UIViewContentMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499376/uiimageview-aspect-fit-and-center)

Comment: Yes I am using Autolayout.

Comment: Share some code or XIB. Add some background color to your UImageView. See whether your UIImageView is getting scaled or not.